# How can I export all calendar entries from iCloud?

Tags: icloud, calendar, sharing, ical

I'm trying to export my calendar for use in Magic Mirror (https://magicmirror.builders), but only one repeating entry is exported, even though I have many entries in my calendar. Is there a setting I'm missing?

I got the URL by going to iCloud calendar and sharing the calendar publicly, and I even looked at the data received by changing the protocol from webcal:// to http://, but I can't see my upcoming entries in the data received, so it's not a problem in the plugin. The entries show up properly in my iDevices and macOS Calendar.app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround for this:

- Make the calendar public in iCloud
- Open the Calendar.app on an iOS device
- Tap the Calendars button on the bottom and then the `i` on the calendar you want to share
- Tap the `Share Link...` button and send the link to yourself somehow

For some reason this link works fine, but the one from https://icloud.com doesn't.